# How to make an image-button run a PHP script?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

What's the best practice to create an image button that sends a value and runs a php script (that executes a mySQL query) when clicked. The button has to be an image and not a default submit type of button. I've been googling this for a few days and I still can't find a sutable answer. I could use GET and make a few image buttons (images with links that contain values) on the page that redirect to itself which then I can collect with

```
if (isset($_GET['variable']))
```

but I don't really want the user to see the values. I tried creating a form which has only one button in it that when clicked will reload the page and I could capture and use the value with

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_value'])) {$var = $_POST['submit_value']; }
```

but I can't seem to make this work, at least not when the button is an image. So if anyone knows a decent way to do this, please share. It doesn't have to be AJAX e.g. page reload is perfectly fine. I'm guessing that I need JavaScript to do this but I don't really know JavaScript so a working example would be nice.

---

SELF-ANSWER

Thank you for all of your answers. I found that the simplest working way to go with is to create a form with an input type of image that makes the submit and an input type of hidden that carries that value.

```
<form action="some_page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="variable" value="50" />
    <input type="image" src="image.png" name="submit" />
</form>
```

And on the PHP side I use this to catch the value.

```
if (isset($_POST['variable'])) { $var = $_POST['variable']; }
```

This is the most suitable solution for my problem. Thank you all again for your speedy responses.

Comment: AJAX is much, much cleaner than making individual forms for each button. Also, why don't you want the user to see the contents of the request?

Comment: @Blender there's no need to create individual forms for each button.

Answer (score 3):

Image buttons are pretty much a mess! :(

I would suggest using CSS to put background-image to ordinary `<input type="submit">`. This way value will always be visible (eg. sent in request) when user submits the form.

For example:

```
.myImageSubmitButton{
    width: 100px;
    height: 22px;
    background: url(images/submit.png) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    /** other CSS **/
}
```

the **bad** thing here is that you must set width and height according to image used...

Answer (score 2):

**if it must be a `<button>`** you can redirect the form to another script like this:

```
<form action="somescript.php" method="POST" name="myform">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="normal submit">
    <button name="foo" type="button" value="bar" 
        onclick="document.myform.action = 'someotherscript.php'; 
                 document.myform.submit()">
        <img src="someimage.png">
    </button>
</form>
```

or change a hidden field and post the form to the same page like this:

```
<form action="somescript.php" method="POST" name="myform">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="normal submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="hidden_action" value="normal_action">
    <button name="foo" type="button" value="bar" 
        onclick="document.getElementById('hidden_action').value = 'special_action'; 
                 document.myform.submit()">
        <img src="someimage.png">
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: if the user wants to, they CAN retrieve the values, for example with Firebug. This cannot be changed.

Also, HTML buttons *can be* images. See [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/299555.aspx).

Or use XMLhttprequest on an image wih onclick. There are many tutorials for XMLHTTPRequest. For example [this](http://jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a POST form and use the image as a submit button without javascript:

```
<input type="image" src="myimage.gif" name="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

invoke a submit using onclick event on the image

```
<img src="image.jpg" onclick="document.formname.submit();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

make submit button with image like that

```
  <input type="submit" style="background-image:url(image); border:none;   
 width:10px;height:10px; color:transparent;" value=" " name="submit_value"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only two ways of doing this are with gets (like you've stated) or with a form where the image button is an input with type submit.

I'm pretty sure you can change the styling of a submit button so that it has a background image, if not then ignore my ignorance.